# RNN in TensorFlow realtime implementation

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to implement a RNN in TensorFlow to track the position of a few objects. I want a realtime implementation so I would give the network a datapoint at the time. The examples I have seen in TensorFlow the input is always a sequence of datapoints at different times.. How can I input only one datapoint at the time?

Comment: I believe you can change the size of the input placeholder to adopt one data.

Or, you can make the placeholder and graph for variable batch size. Could you provide your code or sample so that we can point how to change it?

Comment: Or, for RNN, you can set only the first data and fill the other data with blank or something. Then get the first output data as your result.

Answer (score 0):

As the Tensorflow documentation, 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

- You can specify the initial state as an input for the RNN network,
- Also, Tensorflow RNN networks output the final state.

Therefore, you can give the input as the shape of [batchsize, 1, inputsize] (don't forget the initial state ;) and will receive an output with the following shape [batchsize, 1, outputsize] and the final state.

Then you can input the final state of the previous execution as the initial state to the next execution.

This will allow you to create a RNN that can run in real-time ;)